# 64bit compatability for 32bit SetTimer Windows callback

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

Previous working 32bit windows c++ application on **32bit windows** now needs to be used on a 64bit windows machine. Using VisualStudio2008. Call is

`SetTimer(m_hWnd, nTimerID, nElapse, *pReceiver)`

which may be found in `WinUser.h`.

I changed my preprocessor definitions from `WIN32` to `WIN64` when compiling. The application compiles and runs on the 64bit pc but the callback is not getting triggered ( the application behaviour makes this obvious ).

Is there a workaround to get this to work?

Comment: Too little information to find the problem. Obviously SetTimer is supposed to work normally under 64-bit Windows. If it doesn't, that indicates a subtle usage problem. (Not surprising given SetTimer's absurd complexity.) The task is not to find a workaround, the task is to find the bug.

Comment: Please post the code that defines and initializes the four variables being passed to `SetTimer`.

Comment: Sebastian Redl, I think you were right. The timer was using Microsoft thunk for 32bit which meant it was not portable.

Comment: Hold on ... did you actually compile the program as 64 bit, or did you just change the macro definitions?  If you build a 32 bit program with 64 bit macros, things definitely aren't going to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class DelayedAction
 {

  public:
  DelayedAction( int expirePeriod, boost::function<void()> callback ):
      work( service),
      thread( boost::bind( &DelayedAction::run, this)),
      timer( service),
      m_callback(callback),
      m_expirePeriod(expirePeriod)
  {}

  ~DelayedAction()
  {
      thread.join();
  }

  void startTimer()
  { 
  }

  void on_some_event()
  {
    startAfter(m_expirePeriod);
  }

  void stop()
  {
    timer.cancel();
  }

  void startAfter( const size_t delay)
  {
      // no need to explicitly cancel
      // timer.cancel();
      timer.expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::seconds( delay) );
      timer.async_wait( boost::bind( &DelayedAction::action, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }



  private:
  void run()
  {
      service.run();
  }

  // ...

  void action(const boost::system::error_code& e) 
  {
      if(e != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
          std::cout << "action" << std::endl;
          m_callback();
  }

  int m_expirePeriod;
  boost::function<void()> m_callback;

  boost::asio::io_service         service;
  boost::asio::io_service::work   work;
  boost::thread                   thread;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer     timer;


 };
```

Comment: I have replaced the old timer with boost deadline_timer, hopefully it works ;-)